# Use of unassigned local variable

Tags: c#, variables, char, local

In my code I am getting the following error:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'nonrpeatedChar'

Why is this error occurring and how do I fix it?

```
static void firstNonRepeated(string str)
{
        int i, j, len;
        len = str.Length;

        int count = 1;
        char nonrpeatedChar;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < len; j++)
            {
                if (i != j && str[i] == str[j])
                {
                    count = count + 1;
                }
            }
            if (count == 1)
            {
                nonrpeatedChar = str[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(nonrpeatedChar);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }           
}
```

Comment: What if `len==0`? What value `nonrpeatedChar` will have?

Comment: If count is never 1, `nonrpeatedChar` will never be assigned a value to and it cannot be read.

Answer (score 5):

Given your code path, there's no guarantee that `nonrepeatedChar` has been assigned to before passing it to `Console.WriteLine` because the only assignment happens inside fo an `if` block which may or may not be hit.

An easy fix would be to assign a default value when you declare it:

```
char nonrepeatedChar = default(char);
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
char nonrpeatedChar = new Char();
```

Comment: Really, because @gvndpmlg1 just posted a new answer saying it solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

If `str` has a len of `0`, the value of `nonrpeatedChar` is undefined. Therefore `Console.WriteLine(nonrpeatedChar);` does not work.